# Is there any way command prompt error logs can be stored somewhere?

Tags: java, cmd, command-line, jar

I have ran a java jar file in command prompt. For suppose the program execution fails with some error, I want the errors to be logged somewhere so that I can check later.

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a command `> output.txt` to store the command line output into a separate file.

```
java -jar application.jar > output.txt
```

you can use location custom location for output.txt as well.

```
java -jar application.jar > D:\\myfolder\\output.txt
```

or you can create a java program to run external jar application using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` which helps you manipulate the output to display and perform actions according to the output.

```
Process myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar application.jar");

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myProcess.getInputStream()));

while ((consoleOutput = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    saveLogs(consoleOutput);
    System.out.println(consoleOutput);
}

myProcess.waitFor();

InputStream in = myProcess.getInputStream();
InputStream err = myProcess.getErrorStream();

byte[] b = new byte[in.available()];
in.read(b, 0, b.length);
saveLogs(consoleOutput);
System.out.println(new String(b));

byte[] c = new byte[err.available()];
err.read(c, 0, c.length);
saveLogs(consoleOutput);
System.out.println(new String(c));
```

Use `FileWriter` to save the consoleOutput into a file.

```
public void saveLogs(String text) {
    try (FileWriter f = new FileWriter("log\\output.log", true);
            BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(f);
            PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(b);) {
        p.println(text);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error("SAVE_LOGS_ERROR", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think logback is what you are looking for (http://logback.qos.ch/index.html).
It helps you to config the log level (infor , debug, error, ...) and the location of the log file.